# Styling jQuery Validation error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I've created a form page using Jade and it is being validated using the jQuery Validation plugin.

I would like to style my error messages, using Bootstrap. I would like to use the `.has-error` class and the `.has-success` class. These have to be used on the parent `div` with class `.form-group`. More details [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation).

I have been playing around with the errorClass, errorElement, errorContainer, ... options, but I can't seem to find the right combination. What am I missing here?

This is my form:

```
form#signupForm.form-horizontal(method='post', action='')
     .form-group
        label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='firstName') 
            | First Name:
        .col-sm-10
            input#firstName.form-control(type='text', placeholder='John',name='firstName')

    .form-group
        label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='lastName')
            | Last Name:
        .col-sm-10
            input#lastName.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Doe', name='lastName')

    .form-group
        .col-sm-2.control-label
            button.btn.btn-default(type='submit')
                | Submit
```

I tried this in my validation code:

```
errorElement: 'div',
errorClass: 'has-error',
```

Comment: Are you having trouble styling the elements according to their class or adding that class on to an element when there is an error?

Comment: Adding that class to a certain element

Comment: A thought on this question - you could improve it by getting rid of the jade, and just showing the generated HTML.  Unless the Jade is part of the problem, it doesn't really add anything to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you're looking for is [errorPlacement](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement), probably combined with the [success](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) option:

> Customize placement of created error labels. First argument: The created error label as a jQuery object. Second argument: The invalid element as a jQuery object.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.closest("div.form-group").removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  },
  success: function(error, element) {
    $(element).closest("div.form-group").addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
  }
});
```

EDIT: I noticed that 1) older versions of the success function are not passed `element` at all, and in newer ones, it's a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, so it must be wrapped in `$(element)`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/7epd44de/

Comment: When I only use the `errorPlacement` option, the form works fine (except, the `has-error` class never disappears ofcourse). But when I add the `success` option, the form is submitted from the moment that 1 value is correct (and the rest wrong or empty)

Comment: Yeah, the `success` option that I suggested was causing it to throw errors I believe!  Check out my edit...

Comment: Ryley, `highlight` and `unhighlight` are the best callback functions for toggling these classes, **not** `errorPlacement` and `success`.  The  `highlight/unhighlight` functions even have the `errorClass` and `validClass` arguments already available to them.

Comment: See:  http://jsfiddle.net/7epd44de/1/ and if you needed to suppress all messages:  http://jsfiddle.net/7epd44de/2/

Comment: Hmm, yes, that does make sense indeed :)